# Azure DevOps App Center distribute task Resource not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to get an on-premise Azure DevOps pipeline working with an App Center distribute task, but I'm at a loss with this error. Why is it still using the depreciated release_uploads path even though I have the recommended 3.173 version? /release_uploads was changed to /uploads/releases, but I don't know how to get the App Center distribute task to use the new path. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my Agent build machine or DevOps.

[Deploy Azure DevOps Builds with App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy)

```
Starting: Distribute artifact via App Center
==============================================================================
Task         : App Center distribute
Description  : Distribute app builds to testers and users via Visual Studio App Center
Version      : 3.173.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/app-center-distribute
==============================================================================
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:6460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): {"message":"Resource not found: /v0.1/apps/MyCompany/MyApp-Alpha-Android/release_uploads/73ff9977-3447-49e6-825a-503c15e1a156. Correlation ID: 34b76a99-39ca-455f-bdd1-212640271356","statusCode":404,"code":"Not Found"}
http response code: 404
Finishing: Distribute artifact via App Center
```

AppCenterDistribute task yaml

```
- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  displayName: 'Distribute artifact via App Center'
  inputs:
      serverEndpoint: 'App Center'
      appSlug: 'MyCompany/MyApp-Alpha-Android'
      appFile: '$(pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.apk'
      releaseNotesOption: 'input'
      releaseNotesInput: 'Alpha'
      destinationType: 'groups'
```

I also had my DevOps admin add the latest App Center distribute Extension to the server, but now there are 2 in the Task list when building the yaml.
[Multiple tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAbuJ.png)

Comment: Not sure of your VSTS agent implementation, but you could check what $(Agent.WorkFolder) and $(Agent.BuildDirectory) are set to. The build directory is set the same as pipeline.Workspace, so maybe you want the work folder.

Comment: You can update the working folder by running this on the agent machine `setx /m VSTS_AGENT_INPUT_WORK "C:\DirectoryYouWant"`